# Class 'ProductDetailViewController' has no initializers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I am trying to create scrollable imageview. Currently using swift 4.0. While running I am getting "has no initializers" error. I am not sure what code brought this error. I am new to swift and I am unable to track what is going on.

`Class 'ProductDetailViewController' has no initializers` I am getting this error.

Can any one please tell me how to fix this error.

Entire view controller code is given below. Thanks in advance

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    //Outlers
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    //Global variables
    var productDict : JSON = []
    var arrayOfProductImageUrls :  Array<Any> = []
    var zoomScroll : UIScrollView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.initialSetup()
        self.scrollViewSetup()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */




    //Mark: - Scrollview Setup

    func initialSetup() {
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewSetup() {

        let productsArray : Array = self.arrayOfProductImageUrls;
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        var frame : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 360)

        for (index, value) in productsArray.enumerated() {

            //Imageview Setup
            let productImageView : UIImageView
            let width : NSInteger = Int(frame.width)
            productImageView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(Int (width * index))
            productImageView.frame.origin.y = 0

            //Scrollview Setup
            zoomScroll.frame = frame;
            zoomScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            zoomScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            zoomScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            zoomScroll.delegate = self
            zoomScroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
            zoomScroll.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
            zoomScroll.tag = index
            zoomScroll.isScrollEnabled = true




            self.scrollView.addSubview(zoomScroll)


            //Setting image
            let imageUrl : URL =  (productsArray[index] as AnyObject).url
            productImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl)

            if index < productsArray.count {

                productImageView.frame = zoomScroll.bounds
                productImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.redraw
                productImageView.clipsToBounds = true
                productImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                zoomScroll.addSubview(productImageView)

            }

            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(frame.origin.x) + CGFloat(width), productImageView.frame.size.height)

        }

    }


    //Mark : Custom methods
    func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }


    func CGSizeMake(_ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

}
```

Comment: Change var zoomScroll : UIScrollView to var zoomScroll : UIScrollView!

Comment: You need to init the zoomScoll variable too or declared as optional like var zoomScroll: UIScrollView?. The Class 'ProductDetailViewController' has no initializers means one of a non-optional variable hasn't been initialized.

Comment: It worked, Can you tell me more about the issue and fix.

Comment: Here is the apple doc about initialization: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Saurabh Prajapati. Nice and quick catch.

For more, The Swift Programming Language states

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an
>   appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or
>   structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an
>   indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an
>   initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the
>   property’s definition.

Let me explain more, the problem was with `scrollView` property that does not have a default value. As above mentioned, all variables in Swift must always have a value or nil (make it optional). When you make it optional, you allow it to be nil by default, removing the need to explicitly give it a value or initialize it.

Here we are using `!` optional so the default value will be `nil`

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
}
```

Setting nil as the default value

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! = nil
}
```

Setting the default value, creating an object now it is not nil.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
}
```

But we can't-do like that, we are not setting the default value here.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView
}
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same echo
it was so easy to solve it by using ! after any variable like this
    var ref: DatabaseReference!